# Access scope variables from delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

This will sound strange, but is it possible to access the properties of a class instance from the delegate implementation? I'd like to give the class user the ability to inject more code and functionality (executed during run-time) into the class. If the following approach is not possible, do I have any other options?

Test.cs:

```
Class Test{
  public int P {get; set;}; 
  public Action A; 
  public void Run(){ 
    this.A(); 
 }
}
```

Main:

```
t = new Test(); 
t.A = () => { /* Modify t.P in here. */}; 
t.Run();
```

Comment: Why not just pass it as a parameter to the delegate?

Comment: The closure should manage this. Have you tried it? Have you encountered any problem?

Comment: There are many properties in the class.

Comment: @Alex your code works (with some minor syntax corrections), but the correct way to do it is the one proposed by haim770

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the question but `t.A = () => { t.P = 100;};` works well in your main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, the `this` keyword is bound to the lexical scope, so it will always refer to the class instance where the `Action` is assigned.

To overcome this, you can simply pass the `Test` instance as a parameter to the `Action` as follows:

```
public class Test
{
    public int P { get; set; }
    public Action<Test> A;
    public void Run()
    {
        this.A(this);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var t = new Test();

t.A = test =>
{
    // you can now access `Test` properties
    var p = test.P;
};

t.Run();
```

Alternatively, you can "capture" your current reference to `t` using a closure, but that would usually require the compiler to generate a type to represent that delegate (which might have performance issues, depending on your scenario):

```
var t = new Test();

t.A = () => {
    // access Test properties using `t`
    var p = t.P;
};

t.Run();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that. the reference to the instance t exists in your scope thus you can refer to it in your inline method like this:

```
t.A = () => { t.P = 3; };
```

- Please note the code example you uploaded won't compile. 'class' should be written with lower case first letter and you did not not declare the variable t type.